# SIM800C - CME ERROR: 15 SIM wrong & CME ERROR: 10 SIM not inserted

Tags: gsm, pcb-antenna, tcp-ip, sim, tracking

I am making a GSM Tracker with SIM800C module. After deploying it into vehicles.. It works fine.. but after some days, it starts responding as **CME ERROR: 15 SIM wrong** for command AT+CPIN? & **CME ERROR: 10 SIM not inserted** for commands required to build TCP Connections. The Commands are written below.

```
  delay(100);
  myGsm.println("AT+CIPSHUT");
  delay(1000);
  printSerialData();

  myGsm.println("AT+CIPMUX=0");
  delay(2000);
  printSerialData();
```

also I checked the potential between SIM800C's SIMVCC & GND it was 1.8 V which is fine.
I am not able to understand the cause of the errors.I have attached the Schematic Of device.[![enter image description here][1]][1] somebody, please suggest the solution as it gets disconnected with the server in between the journey & tracker losts.

Edit:- Here are my Some Observations :-

1. On Soft resetting the Module i.e. by giving AT Command AT+CFUN=1,1, error resolves but I don't want to use this as this is a temporary solution. it starts giving the error again.
2. There is no effect of hard resetting the MCU.
3. The error resolves after reinserting the battery but this will not work as  I can't do this from server side.

Please, somebody, tell the cause of the problem so that I can take it as use-case in my development.

Comment: Vibration? Unstable power supply? Try soft-resetting the module when it replies with a SIM error.

Comment: On Soft resetting the Module i.e. by giving AT Command AT+CFUN=1,1, error resolves but I don't want to use this as this is a temporary solution. it starts giving the error again after some time. please tell the cause of the error. and how to check the vibration..? @filo

Comment: Run it for one week on the table. If no failures happen then simply it is the environment in the vehicle that affects your device. I would bet on supply voltage (add capacitors or a better power supply) and mechanical assembly/vibration.

Comment: Exactly.! it works fine on the table.  & I have added 100nf capacitor with VBATT pin of SIM800C, is there any problem in this..? &  please throw some light on mechanical assembly/vibration.

Comment: How? You did not post the PCB, nor photos.

Comment: I added the Photo of PCB. Please tell the capacitor is fine..? & Tell something about mechanical assembly/vibration @filo

Comment: @bandejiya - "*I added the Photo of PCB*" (a) Is this a new design, and you are seeing the reported error messages from the start of deployment into vehicles? In other words, has the design has been "unreliable" from the beginning? Please give more context of situation. (b) The PCB does not seem to match the schematic! e.g. no MIC29302 regulator visible on the PCB; R3 - R6 (between MCU UART and GSM UART) shown on schematic, but only R3 seems visible in perhaps the expected area of the PCB etc. etc. so it's impossible to analyse (I think there are mistakes in this area of the schematic anyway).

Comment: Having worked with the SIM900 in the past, and collaborating with others who have used this... these SIM modules are unreliable. Because you can't remove/reinsert battery in the field, you should use a MOSFET on the power line and have your code periodically power cycle the module. It is an inelegant but robust solution that will keep you from pulling your hair out.

Comment: @SamGibson Can you please share your Email ID I want to share the documents with you. & a) this error comes after some time i.e. this design works fine if the device is constantly on one location. & after deploying into vehicle it works fine for some days but later it stops pinging the data..! b)I had mistakenly shared old version of schematic please share your ID I want to share all the documents.

Comment: @bandejiya - (Thanks for your offer of email, but all updates need to be put into the question, not by email.) (a) Here is my understanding: This design always had the problem you described, soon after it is installed in at least *some* cars. There are no problems using it on your bench, with a power supply there. It is not clear to me if you have done testing in a *car* which is in one location (e.g. in a car park space) but whose engine *is* being started & stopped. (b) Your latest update has removed the PCB photo, please fix! "*mistakenly shared old version of schematic*" Fix that too! :-(

Comment: Thanks @SamGibson . I have done testing by putting them into moving trucks. & I have asked to higher authorities to get the final schematic..! soon I will post as I receive it.

Comment: @filo how do you confidently bet that the problem is on supply voltage or mechanical vibrations..?

Comment: Because you said so. "it works fine on the table" I'd also add EMI to the mix (especially on the SIM lines). You could try a metal enclosure.

Comment: @filo because the tracker is in moving vehicle. can it give the same error while changing the tower to whom it is registered or entering to coverage area from out of coverage area or vice versa? if yes than how..?